# New Hover Functionality in General Tab

Tags: activex, teechart

I am using TeeChart2015X64.ocx, I see a new hover functionality in General Tab, The issue is when the number of Points on X-Axis are high then  Mouseover in chart x-axis highlights wrong x-axis labels.

Can Anyone let me know how to disable this functionality from code since I don't see any function for the same.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
TChart1.Hover.Visible = False
```

**Edit 1:**

For VC++, download the Hover headers from [here](http://www.teechart.net/files/public/support/VCHover.zip) and extract with the other TeeChart headers.

**Edit 2:**

To disable the Hover only for the bottom axis you can do this:

```
TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Selected.Hover.Visible = False
```

Comment: This is not present in VC++

Comment: Actually with new TeeChart 2015 there is a new function get_hover but this doesn;t have any associate class, how can I use this.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link to the Hover headers.

Comment: Thank Yeray, this works fine, one more question is there a way to  disable the hover only on the X-Axis Label and not everywhere.

Comment: I've edited the answer again. Please accept the answer if it solves the initial question and open a new question if you have different doubts